# How to get height of image manipulated with css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I'm having some div boxes where there is an image inside. What I want it to do, is to add a class to the image if the image height is smaller than the div boxs height its inside.

But I have set the image to be a 100% width of the div box with css, so when I use jquery's .Height() on the image, it gives me the original size. Any suggestions?

```
<div class="boxe">
    <asp:Literal ID="imgProjekt1" runat="server" />
    <asp:Literal ID="litProjekt1" runat="server"/>
</div>

<div class="boxe forsideboxMiddle">
    <asp:Literal ID="imgProjekt2" runat="server" />
    <asp:Literal ID="litProjekt2" runat="server"/>
</div>
```

The literal with the ID imgProjekt1 and ImgProjekt2 makes a normal img tag from codebehind.

Comment: Have you tried using `max-height` and `max-width`?

Comment: Have you tried `$(img).outerHeight()`?

Comment: max-height and max-with wont be helpfull in this situation

Comment: with outerheight it puts the classes on all divs, also them where the image is bigger than the div or same size

Answer (score 2):

try

```
var currentContentHeight = contentElement.offsetHeight;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use clientWidth & clientHeight.

```
var img = document.getElementById('imgProjekt1'); 
var width = img.clientWidth;
var height = img.clientHeight;
```

Edit:

```
$(window).load(function () { 
    var image = $('.boxe img');
    var box = $(".boxe");
    if (image[0].clientHeight > box[0].clientHeight) { 
        image.addClass('billedMiddle');
    }
});
```

Comment: i Cant get that to work:

$(window).load(function () {
            var image = $('.boxe img');
            var width = image.clientWidth;
            var height = image.clientHeight;
            var box = $(".boxe");
            if (height > box.clientHeight()) {
                image.addClass('billedMiddle');
            }
        });

Comment: `clientWidth` and `clientHeight` are properties of the DOM element. You can do this: `var image = $('.boxe img')[0]; var box = $(".boxe")[0];`

Comment: So how should the script look then?

Comment: Thanks, bu that script makes all the images get that class, and it should only be the images that has a smaller height than the box and if i turn the > arround that doesnt work either

Answer (score 0):

use window.getComputedStyle to get current DOM's object style value. Below is code example of how to extract height and width of dom object.

```
function Scale(width_offset, height_offset) {
   var imgs = document.getElementsByClassName("your img tag class name");
   for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
     var curr_width = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(imgs[i]).width); // extract dom's width
     var curr_height = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(imgs[i]).height); //extract dom's height
     imgs[i].style.width = curr_width + width_offset + "px";
     imgs[i].style.height = curr_height + height_offset + "px";
   }
}
```